# NSXML Parser and loading a level cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xml-parsing

I am trying to load my levels in objective-c through xml.

Here is the style of my xml that is output from my level editor.

```
 <level>
  <entity>
    <name>grey</name>
    <id>5</id>
    <body>false</body>
    <x>0.0</x>
    <y>0.0</y>
    <rotation>0.0</rotation>
  </entity>
 <entity>
    <name>grey</name>
    <id>5</id>
    <body>false</body>
    <x>0.0</x>
    <y>0.0</y>
    <rotation>0.0</rotation>
  </entity>
 </level>
```

Each game object is recognized in XML as its own entity(Sprite when it is loaded int the game). So when the parsing takes place each entity or CCSprite should have its own x and y.

I would like the parser to traverse the xml document so each entity has a name, x, and y, and rotation. The other elements im not concerned with yet.

I have been trying for hours now to get things up and running with NSXML parser but no luck thus far..Here is what i have tried so far.

```
    NSString* currentElement;


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

currentElement = elementName;

}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

 if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]){
     NSLog(@"Name found: %@", string);

 }

 }
```

This works for some of the elements but the problem is foundCharacters is called multiple times and sometimes the name string returns blank.

What i am trying to do is when a element "name is found, i want to call a method that adds the current entity to the scene taking the "Name", "X, and "Y" elements as paramters.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116827/looking-for-a-good-tutorial-on-nsxmlparser and specifically http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

Comment: Hmm..It still doesnt seem to be what i need.

Comment: Why don't you use plist instead of xml??

Comment: I am not familiar with plist